# pip: to sudo or not to sudo

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip and I am drowning in conflicting answers in StackOverflow (pls read remark at end for duplicated questions).

The [instructions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) said to download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run it using phyton:

```
python get-pip.py
```

When I follow the instructions as is I get:
[image]

When I use the --user option:

```
python get-pip.py --user
```

Other problem arises later and anyhow it is not endorsed:

> The pip developers are considering making --user the default for all installs, including get-pip.py installs of pip, but at this time, --user installs for pip itself, should not be considered to be fully tested or endorsed. For discussion, see [Issue 1668](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1668).

So I go the sudo way:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

It is successful but with a warning:
[image]

So I use the -H flag after deleting the previous installation:

```
sudo -H python get-pip.py
```

Everything seems fine and I have access to pip:

[image]

And then I try to install the virualenv package:

```
pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

And get a permission denied error:

> IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py'

As several answers in StackOverflow discourages the use of sudo when installing pip packages I am stuck here. How to proceed?

-- Please don't mark as duplicate as so many questions in StackOverflow have conflicting answers and none, from the dozen or so I read, seems to direct to how to solve this issue.

Comment: The quotes you provided say that installing **pip itself** with `--user` is not officially supported, **but installing other packages is 100% fine!**. So just use the `--user` option for `virtualenv`.

Comment: Ok, I did not realise that from the quote. Thank you. It now works fine.

Comment: @Bakurio Would you like to submit your comment as an answer?

Comment: As @Bakurio did not follow your suggestion please answer this question yourself and accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by @Bakuriu in the comments:
The quotes I provided say that installing pip itself with --user is not officially supported, but installing other packages is 100% fine!. So just use the --user option for virtualenv.